# Reverse-engineer a Word DOCX generated by XML back to XML

Tags: xml, ms-word, openxml, docx

I have a word document that was originally generated using XML. Now I want to reverse-engineer it back to XML and get the original XML code. What's the best way to do it?

Comment: By word document, what file extension are you talking about?

Comment: So the word doc is .docx and I want to get the original XML code out of it.

Comment: Do you know what encoding .docx files have?

Comment: There is no *original XML code*.

Comment: If you encoded an xml document into a .docx file, and know the encoding set of .docx files, what you can do is decode your .docx file into an XML file in whatever language you want. As @KenWhite points out, if you don't have any original XML format, you'll have to build out an XML file however you need it (there are no explicit known conversions of .docx into .xml).

Comment: it should be ANSI according to notepad!

Comment: damn. alright, thanks :)

Comment: Was your original XML text or data oriented?  If data-oriented, you could have constructed a Word document using content control data binding.  If you did it this way, you can simply extract the corresponding XML part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern Word documents (DOCX) are based upon [OOXML](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm), consisting of two parts:

- Open Packaging Conventions (OPC), which is Zip-based.  You can rename
  a DOCX file extension to .zip and use normal Zip utilities to open
  it.
- WordprocessingML, which is XML-based.  You can use regular XML tools
  and parsers to read and write.

So, in a way, your DOCX file is already XML.  Regarding "originally generated", well, that's a question of data provenance rather than data formats.  Other than some metadata about authorship, creation date/time, etc, there is nothing to use for reverse-engineering a DOCX file that can take you back to the source data upon which it was derived.